# VBA Macro attached to the file

Tags: vba, excel

I have 9 macros that are used to perform different functions. 
This is how i use them:

1. Put content in the excel sheet
2. Run the macros by pressing buttons to format and make changes
3. Copy the file, remove old content and start fresh with new content

I have buttons on the sheet which when pressed run the macro and everything works fine. I decided to remove the buttons from the sheet (imagine 9 buttons on the sheet) and put them in a menu (by customizing the ribbon). However when I copy the previous file, rename it, remove the content & run the macros, they are all linked to the previous sheet.

Here is one of the macros. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm dynamically determining the workbook path and then I'm working based on that. When I run the code in new sheet the workbook path is also for the sheet in which I put macro in the menu.

I'm curious as to why is this happening, is there anything that I can do to avoid this.

Note: I came across activesheet but then that sounded more like a workaround. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Sub Seatholderpull()
    Dim tText As String, str() As String
    '(Done) Pull seatholder names from  documents
    ' (Done) Rename seat holder documents in
    'Cut Paste Seat Holder documents in  Folder
    workbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    workbookPath = Left(workbookPath, Len(workbookPath) - 4)
    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    pathFile = workbookPath & "\Cc Documents\"
    'MsgBox (pathfile)
    Set pptDeckApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptDeckApp.Visible = True

    Dim filename As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim k As Integer
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(pathFile)
    Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files
    'usageFileCheck = 0
    ' Open Usage File
    For Each myFile In MyFiles
        chkExtFound = 0
        chkReport = 0
        chkSH = 0
        chkExtFound = InStr(1, myFile.name, ".pptx", 1)
        chkReport = InStr(1, myFile.name, "Impact_Assessment_report", 1)
        MsgBox (myFile.name)
        'chkSH = InStr(1, myFile.name, nameSh, 1)
        If (chkExtFound <> 0 And chkReport <> 0) Then
            usageDeckDestination = pathFile & myFile.name
            On Error Resume Next

            'MsgBox (usageDeckDestination)

            Set usagedeck = pptDeckApp.Presentations.Open(usageDeckDestination)
            tText = (usagedeck.Slides(1).Shapes("Rectangle 5").TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
            'MsgBox (tText)


            str = VBA.Split(tText, vbCr)
            'MsgBox (str(2))
            If (Len(str(2)) < 2) Then
                str(2) = "Account"

                For k = 1 To 7
                    'MsgBox ("in For")
                    usagedeck.Slides(k).Select
                    titl = (usagedeck.Slides(k).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
                    'MsgBox (titl)
                    If (InStr(1, titl, "Value Review from", 1) <> 0) Then
                        Worksheets("Seatholder Matrix").Cells(3, i).Value = usagedeck.Slides(k).Shapes("Group 58").Table.cell(3, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                i = i + 1
            End If

            'pull KI

            usagedeck.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.  See *templates* in Help.

Comment: Apologies, After reading I realized that it sounded more like help with customized menu. I lost the essence of question while wording it. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path for just the path itself (without the workbook name) or Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName for the path with the workbook name.